# Measuring distance in SO(n)

Tags: trigonometry, rotations

I'm trying to find a way to measure the distance between two rotation matrices. For my application, I need a measure that works in $SO(2)$ and one that works in $SO(3)$, but apart from that, I am much more curious about the general $SO(n)$ case. I can find measures for $SO(2)$ and $SO(3)$, but I have no idea how to approach the general case.

For $SO(3)$ I found this [very insightful blog post](http://www.boris-belousov.net/2016/12/01/quat-dist/#:%7E:text=The%20difference%20rotation%20matrix%20that,matrix%20R%20%3D%20P%20Q%20%E2%88%97%20.). It uses $P$ and $Q$ to denote 3x3 rotation matrices and $*$ to denote the matrix transpose. It then measures distance using

$$\theta = \arccos\left(\frac{\mathrm{tr}(PQ^*) - 1}{2}\right).$$

For $SO(2)$ I can come up with a similar formula (with the [help of Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#Properties)):

$$\theta = \arccos\left(\frac{\mathrm{tr}(PQ^*)}{2}\right)$$

This makes me think that there should be a formula for $SO(n)$, but how do I work that out?

---

For context:

My application is to do inverse kinematics on a kinematic chain. Which is buzzword bingo for "I have a parameterized sequence of affine transformations (typically rotations and translations) and I am trying to find a set of parameters such that the transformation of the total sequence results in a desired translation and orientation".

In my case, I am interested in solving the above for a desired orientation only. One way to do so is via optimization, but for that, I need a way of measuring the distance between the current orientation and the desired orientation.

Comment: In dimension $2n, 2n+1$ you will have $n$-angles. It is not clear how to extract those angles by $PQ^*$ alone.

Comment: @ArcticChar good point. Does this mean that there is no straightforward way to measure distance in $SO(4)$ and above?

Comment: In dimension $4$ you might still have a formula (with some work). But in general I guess no.

Comment: If you are comfortable with differential geometry, you can try using curve lengths in $SO(n)$ to measure distances. In particular, you can define the distance between two matrices $A$ and $B$ inside $SO(n)$ as the infimum of all the curve lengths of curves joining $A$ and $B$ (notice that since $SO(n)$ is connected, the infimum exists). However, this requires some understanding of differential manifolds (and Riemannian metrics).

Comment: But that is not a formula, @AniruddhaDeshmukh

Comment: The map $(P,Q)\mapsto {\rm tr}(PQ^*)$ is an *inner product* on $GL(n)$, so the same formula can apply in a sense. However, I'm not sure that would give the length of the shortest smooth curve between $P$ and $Q$ within $SO(n)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that there's no intrinsic notion of "distance" between rotations. Clearly you're referring to some kind of [distance function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_(mathematics)), but there are many different distance functions on $SO(n)$, even when we add some sensible requirements. Which distance function to use largely depends on what you want to *do* with it. For instance, one simple choice is the Euclidean distance $d(A,B)=\|A-B\|$, where $\|A\|^2=\operatorname{tr}(A^TA)=\sum_{i,j}A_{ij}^2$, which is useful in some ways (it is bi-invariant and easy to compute), but not so useful in others (it doesn't have geodesics).

That said, the "standard" choice of distance is the geodesic distance arising from a particular [Riemannian metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemannian_manifold); that metric can be written as $g(U,V)=\operatorname{tr}(U^TV)$, where we interpret tangent vectors in $TSO(n)$ as $n\times n$ matrices in the standard way.

It's possible to compute this geodesic distance using eigenvalues. One can show that the eigenvalues of a rotation matrix consists of $1$s and pairs of complex conjugates of unit magnitude:
$$
(\lambda_1,\cdots,\lambda_n)=\left(1,\cdots,1,e^{i\theta_1},e^{-i\theta_1}\cdots e^{i\theta_k},e^{-i\theta_k}\right)
$$
Where $\theta_1,\cdots,\theta_k\in(-\pi,\pi]$ represent the rotation angles along $k\le n/2$ orthogonal planes. The geodesic distance discussed above has the form
$$
d(A,B)=\sqrt{\theta_1^2+\cdots+\theta_k^2}
$$
Where $\theta_1,\cdots,\theta_k$ are the rotation angles corresponding to the eigenvalues of $A^TB$.

The formulas you've listed agree with this distance. Computing it in higher dimension may require computing the eigenvalues of $A^TB$ directly though, as in dimension $\ge 4$ there will be multiple rotation angles, which can't be extracted as easily.

Comment: Thanks. Do have a good reference to read more details about this?

Comment: One way to think of the distance between rotations A, B ∈ SO(n) is to consider the distance of A^t B to the identity I. Let M = A^t B. Then there is a decomposition of R^n into orthogonal 2-planes preserved by M (and one more, fixed, orthogonal line if n is odd). The product of the unit circle in these 2-planes forms a torus T*k, where k = floor(n/2). The torus has a natural metric (with volume (2π)^k), and is preserved by M. The distance between A and B may be defined quite naturally as the distance that M moves points on T^k. This can be shown to be a bi-invariant Riemannian metric on SO(n).

Comment: In my comment above: "the distance that M moves points on T^k" should be understood as the distance *along T^k* that M moves points on T^k. This is identical to the square root of the sum of the squared angles _j. (And although it does not change the formula: I would say the _j should be chosen from the interval [0, π], not from (-π, π], since only the magnitudes — not the signs — of the angles are determined by the matrix.)